# jQuery hide specific option when specific value is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a function that hides specific options when I select a specific value. My selectbox `#exampleSelect1` contains 3 values: `Greenline_Veranda, Profiline_Veranda, Highline_Veranda` Each value has specific colors that i need to show.

The colors are stored in my Database, I fill these colors in the selectbox `#exampleSelect2`. But I dont want to show all the colors for all the values of `#exampleSelect1`.

Example:

I have 5 colors in my Database: `Green, Blue, Purple, Pink, Yellow`
First of all I select `Greenline_Veranda` in selectbox `#exampleSelect1` I want only to show the colors `Green, Yellow` in `#exampleSelect2` for the `Greenline_Veranda`. But when I change the value of `#exampleSelect1` I want to show other colors for that specific value.

I already have a function working but it is a lot of code and I think there is a easier way of doing it.

Here is the HTML Code:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleSelect1">Ik ben op zoek naar een:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="exampleSelect1" name="typeSelect">
     <option selected="selected">Selecteer een type</option>
      <?php
                  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                        // output data of each row
                        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                            echo "<option value='".$row["opzoekValue"]."'>" . $row["opzoekName"]. "</option>";
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo "0 results";
                    }   
              ?>
    </select>
  </div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleSelect1">Kleurstelling:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="exampleSelect2">
     <option selected="selected">Selecteer een kleur</option>
      <?php
                  if ($resultKleur->num_rows > 0) {
                        // output data of each row
                        while($row = $resultKleur->fetch_assoc()) {
                            echo "<option value='".$row["kleurValue"]."'>" . $row["kleurName"]. "</option>";
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo "0 results";
                    }   
              ?>
    </select>
  </div>
```

And here is the Javascript function to show specific colors on specific values.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#exampleSelect1").change(function() {
      var val = $(this).val();
      if(val == 'Greenline_Veranda') {
          $('#form-zonwering').css('display', 'block');
          $("select option:contains('Blauw Structuurlak')").css("display","none");
          $("select option:contains('Ral 9016')").css("display","none");
          $("select option:contains('Ral 9001')").css("display","none");
          $("select option:contains('Brons Structuurlak')").css("display","none");
          $("select option:contains('Silver Structuurlak')").css("display","none");
          $("select option:contains('Licht Eiken')").css("display","none");
          $("select option:contains('Donker Eiken')").css("display","none");
          $("select option:contains('Zwart Structuurlak')").css("display","none");
          $("select option:contains('Bruin Structuurlak')").css("display","none");
          $("select option:contains('Grijs Structuurlak')").css("display","none");
          $("select option:contains('Rood Structuurlak')").css("display","none");
          $("select option:contains('Groen Structuurlak')").css("display","none");
          $("select option:contains('Ral 9001 Structuurlak')").css("display","none");
          $("select option:contains('Eluxal EV-1')").css("display","none");
      } else if (val == 'Profiline_Veranda') {
          $('#form-zonwering').css('display', 'block');
          $("select option:contains('Blauw Structuurlak')").css("display","block");
          $("select option:contains('Ral 9016')").css("display","block");
          $("select option:contains('Ral 9001')").css("display","block");
          $("select option:contains('Brons Structuurlak')").css("display","block");
          $("select option:contains('Silver Structuurlak')").css("display","block");
          $("select option:contains('Licht Eiken')").css("display","block");
          $("select option:contains('Donker Eiken')").css("display","block");
          $("select option:contains('Zwart Structuurlak')").css("display","block");
          $("select option:contains('Bruin Structuurlak')").css("display","block");
          $("select option:contains('Grijs Structuurlak')").css("display","block");
          $("select option:contains('Rood Structuurlak')").css("display","block");
          $("select option:contains('Groen Structuurlak')").css("display","block");
          $("select option:contains('Ral 9001 Structuurlak')").css("display","block");
          $("select option:contains('Eluxal EV-1')").css("display","block");
          $("select option:contains('Antraciet Structuurlak')").css("display","block");
          $("select option:contains('Ral 9010 Structuurlak')").css("display","none");
      } else {
      $('#form-zonwering').css('display', 'none');
      $("select option:contains('Blauw Structuurlak')").css("display","block");
      $("select option:contains('Ral 9016')").css("display","block");
      $("select option:contains('Ral 9001')").css("display","block");
      $("select option:contains('Brons Structuurlak')").css("display","block");
      $("select option:contains('Silver Structuurlak')").css("display","block");
      $("select option:contains('Licht Eiken')").css("display","block");
      $("select option:contains('Donker Eiken')").css("display","block");
      $("select option:contains('Zwart Structuurlak')").css("display","block");
      $("select option:contains('Bruin Structuurlak')").css("display","block");
      $("select option:contains('Grijs Structuurlak')").css("display","block");
      $("select option:contains('Rood Structuurlak')").css("display","block");
      $("select option:contains('Groen Structuurlak')").css("display","block");
      $("select option:contains('Ral 9001 Structuurlak')").css("display","block");
      $("select option:contains('Eluxal EV-1')").css("display","block");
      }
  });
});
```

So my question is, can I make the Javascript function shorter so I can use it on more selectboxes?

Comment: Yes you can do it without this much line of code. Let me create a fiddle for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code.

### HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleSelect1">Ik ben op zoek naar een:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="exampleSelect1" name="typeSelect">
     <option selected="selected" value="">Selecteer een type</option>
     <option value="Greenline_Veranda">Greenline Veranda</option>
     <option value="Profiline_Veranda">Profiline Veranda</option>
    </select>
  </div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleSelect2">Kleurstelling:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="exampleSelect2">
     <option selected="selected">Selecteer een kleur</option>
       <option attr-value="Greenline_Veranda">Greenline Veranda</option>
       <option attr-value="Profiline_Veranda">Profiline Veranda</option>
       <option attr-value="Greenline_Veranda">Greenline Veranda</option>
       <option attr-value="Profiline_Veranda">Profiline Veranda</option>
       <option attr-value="Greenline_Veranda">Greenline Veranda</option>
       <option attr-value="Profiline_Veranda">Profiline Veranda</option>
       <option attr-value="Greenline_Veranda">Greenline Veranda</option>
       <option attr-value="Profiline_Veranda">Profiline Veranda</option>
       <option attr-value="Greenline_Veranda">Greenline Veranda</option>
       <option attr-value="Profiline_Veranda">Profiline Veranda</option> 
    </select>
  </div>
```

### JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#exampleSelect1").change(function() {
      var val = $(this).val();
      if(val == ''){
      $("#exampleSelect2").find("option").show();
      }else{
      $("#exampleSelect2").find("option:not([attr-value='"+val+"'])").hide();
      $("#exampleSelect2").find("option[attr-value='"+val+"']").show();
      }
  });
});
```

You can bind the value of first select options to the attr-value of second select options. Here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SmitRaval/xpvt214o/96982/)

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that `#exampleSelect2` gets data from my Database so an option will be: `<option attr-value="Purple">Purple</option>`

Comment: I know that, it was just an example. You must have a relationship between color and the values of 1st select box's options. So in your loop you need to manipulate the code to bind the color with selectbox1's value. Getting my point? @JariRengeling